# MySQL Resetting the index count to 0

Tags: mysql, count, indexing

I need to reset my table counter back to 0 - is there a MySQL command for this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

That's easy:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=0;
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, I had to use ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

Comment: Setting the increment to 0 will not work- in all of my testing, you have to set it to a minimum value of 1

Answer (score 19):

You can also use the TRUNCATE statement.  It will remove all the data and reset the auto increment.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName];
```

Is the same as

```
DELETE * FROM [TableName];
ALTER TABLE [TableName] AUTO_INCREMENT = 0;
```

Comment: `TRUNCATE` will not work if there are any tables with a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on it.